# Docusign signature is not showing the frame around it while I have it in the signing settings

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign signature is not having the frame around it. I tried saving this setting multiple times in the signing settings. Cross-checked and validated multiple times. Any ideas??

[Snapshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TS6D.png)

[Snap of signature appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLDoW.png)

Comment: Are you sue it's the same account? do you have a developer account by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you open a case with the [DocuSign support team](https://support.docusign.com/CSP_DSClogin?startURL=%2Fen%2FcaseOverview%3Fdfl%3D1).